# PHP my registration information is not sending data to the database

Tags: php, sql

My code is not sending data to the database but it lets me have my own error like DB error or something. tried check my database it seems to be perfect. in the post method the register is the name of the button

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['register']))
        {
            @$username=$_POST['username'];
            @$password=$_POST['password'];
            @$cpassword=$_POST['cpassword'];
            @$role=$_POST['role'];

            if($password==$cpassword)
            {
                $query = "SELECT * FROM usersample WHERE username='$username'";
                //echo $query;
            $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            //echo mysql_num_rows($query_run);
            if($query_run)
                {
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
                    {
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("This Username Already exists.. Please try another username!")</script>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $query = "INSERT INTO usersample(username,password,role)" ." values('$username','$password','$role')";
                        $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                        if($query_run)
                        {
                            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("User Registered.. Welcome")</script>';
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                            header( "Location: index.php");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<p class="bg-danger msg-block">Registration Unsuccessful due to server error. Please try later</p>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("DB error")</script>';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Password and Confirm Password do not match")</script>';
            }

        }
        else
        {
        }
    ?>
```

This is my dbconnect and i already doublechecked everything and it seems there's not mistake in my code
dbconnect.php

```
    <?php 
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "fransdemo";

$con = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("connection failed");
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: what is `$con` in `$query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);` ? you have not included `dbconnect.php` in your registration code..

Comment: Without the `@`s do you get notices? You are open to SQL injections and should be hashing your user's passwords.

Comment: already included it session_start();
 require_once('database-config.php');

Comment: you are not returning `$con` from `dbconnect.php`. try adding `return $con;` after `echo "Connected successfully";`.

Comment: I suppose he is including the file, it would have thrown an undefined variable `$con` if it was not defined.